# Get just jQuery with bower

Tags: javascript, jquery, linux, bower

Hei

Is it possible to get only jquery.min.js. When running

```
bower install jquery#1.9.0
```

I get a lot of stuff that I will never need. I am not interested to have their Gruntfile in my project.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `bower-installer`. Install [this npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bower-installer) and then just add this properties to bower.json file:

```
"dependencies" : {
    "jquery" : "~1.9.0"
},
"install" : {
    "path" : "path-to-your-vendor-files",
    "sources": {
        "jquery" : [
            "components/jquery/master/jquery.min.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

Then run this command: `bower-installer`. Hope that's what you're after!

Comment: That's the good point! Was seconds away from posting before you do :)