# Bower - Get only files needed (not entire Repo)

Tags: bower

I am trying to use Bower to install jquery. 
The frustrating problem I have been running into is that bower downloads the entire repro. I was hoping to tell bower to install a certain version of jquery and have only those files downloaded.

- I did try the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389972/get-just-jquery-with-bower) with no luck. The entire repo is still downloaded even after clearing the bower cache
- I would rather have something else manage which files to download than me manually specifying the file names in bower.json

bower.json in the repo : https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/bower.json

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't unterstand the meening of bower:

Bower is handling you dependencys, so if you do a:

```
bower install jquery
```

it should download all files.

Now to you question:

you have following options:

1. declare wich file you want to download:

   bower install http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js

but remember:
this file cant be updated easily

2. search for a js only package:

   expample with bootstrap:

   `bower install bootstrap-css-only`

but remember:
these packages sometimes are not up to date

3. use bower-installer (recommended):

   install the bower-installer:

   `npm install bower-installer --global`

and now follow the tutorial:

[bower-installer github](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer)

sorry for my bad english :-)